# Deleting a row in a table doesn't affect the results of pg_table_size or pg_total_relation_size

Tags: postgresql

My ultimate goal is to find how much space on disc a row, or more precisely a query, consumes, along with whatever is stored in a toast table, indexes, etc., but in the process I noticed that after deleting a row, the results of `pg_table_size` and `pg_total_relation_size` stayed the same.

The query I'm useing:

`select count(*), pg_table_size('base_statisticvalue'), pg_total_relation_size('base_statisticvalue') from base_statisticvalue limit 1;`

The results before and after, respectively:

```
11628446,700645376,1223450624
11628445,700645376,1223450624
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 2):

When deleting rows in a table the related space is flagged as free but is not released to file system: you may need to run VACUUM FULL to release space.

```
postgres=# insert into t select generate_series(1,100000);
INSERT 0 100000
postgres=# select count(*) from t;
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

postgres=# select pg_table_size('t')/1024/1024 as mb;
 mb 
----
  3
(1 row)

postgres=# delete from t where x % 2 = 0;
DELETE 50000
postgres=# select count(*) from t;
 count 
-------
 50000
(1 row)

postgres=# select pg_table_size('t')/1024/1024 as mb;
 mb 
----
  3
(1 row)

postgres=# analyze t;
ANALYZE
postgres=# select pg_table_size('t')/1024/1024 as mb;
 mb 
----
  3
(1 row)

postgres=# vacuum t;
VACUUM
postgres=# select pg_table_size('t')/1024/1024 as mb;
 mb 
----
  3
(1 row)

postgres=# vacuum full t;
VACUUM
postgres=# select pg_table_size('t')/1024/1024 as mb;
 mb 
----
  1
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. After running `vaccuum` the results of both pg_table_size and pg_total_relation_size are larger than before. I'm clearly doing something dumb, so I appreciate your patience

Comment: It likely means that more data has been added to the table with INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` doesn't free up any space. It simply marks the part of the block that contained the row as "free" - the block itself might even still contain active rows.

The only way to reclaim storage space after you delete a large part of the rows is to run `vacuum full` on the table in question.